# Shopping Cart in HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is what I have so far. I want to be able to have it so when the checkboxes are checked, items would add up in grand value. I don't know what's wrong with the code, I've been following a youtube video.

It could be as many items checked. This is an easy version of a shopping cart I want to do.

```js
var Cost,Grand_Total,GST,PST;
function price() {
 Cost = 0;
 Cost = dollar(Cost);
 if (document.orderform.Item1.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item2.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item3.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item4.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item5.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item6.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item7.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item8.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item9.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item10.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item11.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item12.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item13.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item14.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item15.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item16.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item17.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item18.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item19.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item20.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item21.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item22.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item23.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item24.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item25.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item26.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item27.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item28.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item29.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item30.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 GST = (Cost*0.07);
 PST = (Cost*0.07);
 GST = dollar(GST);
 PST = dollar(PST);
 Grand_Total = parseFloat(Cost) + parseFloat(GST) + parseFloat(PST);
 Grand_Total = dollar(Grand_Total);
 document.orderform.Total.value = "$" + Cost;
 document.orderform.GST.value = "$" + GST;
 document.orderform.PST.value = "$" + PST;
 document.orderform.GrandTotal.value = "$" + Grand_Total;
}

function dollar (amount) {
 amount = parseInt(amount*100);
 amount = parseFloat(amount/100);
 if (((amount) == Math.floor(amount))&&((amount - Math.floor(amount)) == 0))
 {
  amount = amount + ".00"
  return amount;
 }
 if (((amount*10) - Math.floor(amount*10)) == 0) {
  amount = amount + "0";
  return amount;
 }
 if (((amount*100 - Math.floor(amount*100)) == 0) {
  amount = amount;
  return amount;
 }
 return amount;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="orderform" action="mailto:xolilyle@gmail.com">
<table style="margin-left: 22.5%; margin-top: 3%; position: absolute; font-size: 20px;">
<tr> <td colspan="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item1_chosen" onclick="price()"> 1. Dragon ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item2_chosen" onclick="price()"> 2. Galaxy ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item3_chosen" onclick="price()"> 3. Wolves ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item4_chosen" onclick="price()"> 4. Jaguar ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item5_chosen" onclick="price()"> 5. New Years ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item6_chosen" onclick="price()"> 6. Festive ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item7_chosen" onclick="price()"> 7. Fierce ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item8_chosen" onclick="price()"> 8. Support ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item9_chosen" onclick="price()"> 9. Luck ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item10_chosen" onclick="price()"> 10. Amor ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item11_chosen" onclick="price()"> 11. Halloween ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item12_chosen" onclick="price()"> 12. Domino ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item13_chosen" onclick="price()"> 13. Banana ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item14_chosen" onclick="price()"> 14. Sea ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item15_chosen" onclick="price()"> 15. Popcorn ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item16_chosen" onclick="price()"> 16. Gamer ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item17_chosen" onclick="price()"> 17. Forest ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item18_chosen" onclick="price()"> 18. Pillar ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item19_chosen" onclick="price()"> 19. Snake ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item20_chosen" onclick="price()"> 20. Bumble ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item21_chosen" onclick="price()"> 21. Dungeon ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item22_chosen" onclick="price()"> 22. Mystical ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item23_chosen" onclick="price()"> 23. Grassy ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item24_chosen" onclick="price()"> 24. Warriors ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item25_chosen" onclick="price()"> 25. Fire ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item26_chosen" onclick="price()"> 26. Wood ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item27_chosen" onclick="price()"> 27. Sky ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item28_chosen" onclick="price()"> 28. Pure ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item29_chosen" onclick="price()"> 29. Crystal ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item30_chosen" onclick="price()"> 30. Pumpkin ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item31_chosen" onclick="price()"> 31. Mint ($5.00) <br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Your Total <input type="text" name="Total" value="$0" size="8" id="jom"></td>
<td> PST (7%) <input type="text" name="PST" value="$0"  size="6"></td>
<td colspan="2"> GST (7%) <input type="text" name="GST" value="$0" size="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Your Total Price Altogether: <input type="text" name="GrandTotal" value="$0" size="8"> </td>
</tr>
<td> Your Contact Name: </td>
<td> First <input type="text" name="firstname" size="15" maxlength="20"> Last <input type="text" name="LastName" size="15" maxlength="20"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Your Address: </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="city" size="20" maxlength="20"> </td>
<td> Province/State: </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="province" size="20" maxlength="30"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Phone number: </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="area" size="3" maxlength="5"> <input type="text" name="phone" size="8" maxlength="10"> </td>
</tr>
<td> Email Address: </td>
<td colspan="2"> <input type="text" name="email" size="30" maxlength="30"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" height="3"> <hr> </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Send Your Order"></td>
<td colspan="2" align="center"> <input type="reset" value="Reset Your Orders"> </td> 
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: I would suggest taking only two or three items to get it working!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale what do you mean by that? : (

Comment: As you are taking 30 item to make a shopping cart instead step by step process will help you to understand the problem

Comment: have a look at posted answer, less code and easy to maintain

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the names of your checkbox items.

In your form element for all the checkboxes you have given the same name

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Item"/>
```

It means that you are refering to only one item for all the checkboxes, instead you need to make different names for different text boxes and fetch it's value

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Item1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item3"/>
.
.
<input type="checkbox" name="Item30"/>
```

Comment: @LilyLe What is there are 100 checkbox's in the HTML code, then?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale We can pass the cost of item as a parameter into the onClick = "price(100)"  function and within the function we calculate the overall cost of how items are selected

Answer (score 1):

I think you should move the line `Cost = dollar(Cost)` downto end of if statements.

And you should name your input with name like "item1" , "item2" etc.

```js
var Cost,Grand_Total,GST,PST;
function price() {
 Cost = 0;
 if (document.orderform.Item1.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item2.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item3.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item4.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}    
 if (document.orderform.Item5.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item6.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item7.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item8.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item9.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item10.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item11.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item12.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item13.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item14.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item15.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item16.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item17.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item18.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item19.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item20.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item21.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item22.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item23.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item24.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item25.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item26.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item27.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item28.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item29.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item30.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 GST = (Cost*0.07);
 PST = (Cost*0.07);
 Cost = dollar(Cost);
 GST = dollar(GST);
 PST = dollar(PST);
 Grand_Total = parseFloat(Cost) + parseFloat(GST) + parseFloat(PST);
 Grand_Total = dollar(Grand_Total);
    document.orderform.Total.value = "$" + Cost;
    document.orderform.GST.value = "$" + GST;
    document.orderform.PST.value = "$" + PST;
    document.orderform.GrandTotal.value = "$" + Grand_Total;
}

function dollar (amount) {
    amount = parseInt(amount*100);
 amount = parseFloat(amount/100);
 if (((amount) == Math.floor(amount))&&((amount - Math.floor(amount)) == 0))
 {
  amount = amount + ".00"
  return amount;
 }
 if (((amount*10) - Math.floor(amount*10)) == 0) {
  amount = amount + "0";
  return amount;
 }
 if ((amount*100 - Math.floor(amount*100)) == 0) {
  amount = amount;
  return amount;
 }
 return amount;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="orderform" action="mailto:xolilyle@gmail.com">
<table style="margin-left: 22.5%; margin-top: 3%; position: absolute; font-size: 20px;">
<tr> <td colspan="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="Item1" value="Item1_chosen" onclick="price()"> 1. Dragon ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item2" value="Item2_chosen" onclick="price()"> 2. Galaxy ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item3" value="Item3_chosen" onclick="price()"> 3. Wolves ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item4" value="Item4_chosen" onclick="price()"> 4. Jaguar ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item5" value="Item5_chosen" onclick="price()"> 5. New Years ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item6" value="Item6_chosen" onclick="price()"> 6. Festive ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item7" value="Item7_chosen" onclick="price()"> 7. Fierce ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item8" value="Item8_chosen" onclick="price()"> 8. Support ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item9" value="Item9_chosen" onclick="price()"> 9. Luck ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item10" value="Item10_chosen" onclick="price()"> 10. Amor ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item11" value="Item11_chosen" onclick="price()"> 11. Halloween ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item12" value="Item12_chosen" onclick="price()"> 12. Domino ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item13" value="Item13_chosen" onclick="price()"> 13. Banana ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item14" value="Item14_chosen" onclick="price()"> 14. Sea ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item15" value="Item15_chosen" onclick="price()"> 15. Popcorn ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item16" value="Item16_chosen" onclick="price()"> 16. Gamer ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item17" value="Item17_chosen" onclick="price()"> 17. Forest ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item18" value="Item18_chosen" onclick="price()"> 18. Pillar ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item19" value="Item19_chosen" onclick="price()"> 19. Snake ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item20" value="Item20_chosen" onclick="price()"> 20. Bumble ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item21" value="Item21_chosen" onclick="price()"> 21. Dungeon ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item22" value="Item22_chosen" onclick="price()"> 22. Mystical ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item23" value="Item23_chosen" onclick="price()"> 23. Grassy ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item24" value="Item24_chosen" onclick="price()"> 24. Warriors ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item25" value="Item25_chosen" onclick="price()"> 25. Fire ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item26" value="Item26_chosen" onclick="price()"> 26. Wood ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item27" value="Item27_chosen" onclick="price()"> 27. Sky ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item28" value="Item28_chosen" onclick="price()"> 28. Pure ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item29" value="Item29_chosen" onclick="price()"> 29. Crystal ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item30" value="Item30_chosen" onclick="price()"> 30. Pumpkin ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item31" value="Item31_chosen" onclick="price()"> 31. Mint ($5.00) <br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Your Total <input type="text" name="Total" value="$0" size="8" id="jom">        </td>
<td> PST (7%) <input type="text" name="PST" value="$0"  size="6"></td>
<td colspan="2"> GST (7%) <input type="text" name="GST" value="$0" size="6">     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Your Total Price Altogether: <input type="text" name="GrandTotal" value="$0" size="8"> </td>
</tr>
<td> Your Contact Name: </td>
<td> First <input type="text" name="firstname" size="15" maxlength="20"> Last      <input type="text" name="LastName" size="15" maxlength="20"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Your Address: </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="city" size="20" maxlength="20"> </td>
<td> Province/State: </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="province" size="20" maxlength="30"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Phone number: </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="area" size="3" maxlength="5"> <input type="text" name="phone" size="8" maxlength="10"> </td>
</tr>
<td> Email Address: </td>
<td colspan="2"> <input type="text" name="email" size="30" maxlength="30">     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" height="3"> <hr> </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Send Your Order">    </td>
<td colspan="2" align="center"> <input type="reset" value="Reset Your Orders">     </td> 
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi resolved all issue kindly check below and go though same.

```js
var Cost,Grand_Total,GST,PST;
function price() {
 Cost = 0;
 
 if (document.orderform.Item1.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item2.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item3.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item4.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item5.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item6.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item7.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item8.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item9.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item10.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item11.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item12.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item13.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item14.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item15.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item16.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item17.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item18.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item19.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item20.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item21.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item22.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item23.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item24.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item25.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item26.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item27.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item28.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item29.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item30.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
    Cost = dollar(Cost);
 GST = (Cost*0.07);
 PST = (Cost*0.07);
 GST = dollar(GST);
 PST = dollar(PST);
 Grand_Total = parseFloat(Cost) + parseFloat(GST) + parseFloat(PST);
 Grand_Total = dollar(Grand_Total);
 document.orderform.Total.value = "$" + Cost;
 document.orderform.GST.value = "$" + GST;
 document.orderform.PST.value = "$" + PST;
 document.orderform.GrandTotal.value = "$" + Grand_Total;
}

function dollar (amount) {
 amount = parseInt(amount*100);
 amount = parseFloat(amount/100);
 if (((amount) == Math.floor(amount))&&((amount - Math.floor(amount)) == 0))
 {
  amount = amount + ".00"
  return amount;
 }
 if (((amount*10) - Math.floor(amount*10)) == 0) {
  amount = amount + "0";
  return amount;
 }
 if (((amount*100 - Math.floor(amount*100))) == 0) {
  amount = amount;
  return amount;
 }
 return amount;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="orderform" action="mailto:xolilyle@gmail.com">
<table style="margin-left: 22.5%; margin-top: 3%; position: absolute; font-size: 20px;">
<tr> <td colspan="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="Item1" value="Item1_chosen" onclick="price()"> 1. Dragon ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item2" value="Item2_chosen" onclick="price()"> 2. Galaxy ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item3" value="Item3_chosen" onclick="price()"> 3. Wolves ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item4" value="Item4_chosen" onclick="price()"> 4. Jaguar ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item5" value="Item5_chosen" onclick="price()"> 5. New Years ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item6" value="Item6_chosen" onclick="price()"> 6. Festive ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item7" value="Item7_chosen" onclick="price()"> 7. Fierce ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item8" value="Item8_chosen" onclick="price()"> 8. Support ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item9" value="Item9_chosen" onclick="price()"> 9. Luck ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item10" value="Item10_chosen" onclick="price()"> 10. Amor ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item11" value="Item11_chosen" onclick="price()"> 11. Halloween ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item12" value="Item12_chosen" onclick="price()"> 12. Domino ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item13" value="Item13_chosen" onclick="price()"> 13. Banana ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item14" value="Item14_chosen" onclick="price()"> 14. Sea ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item15" value="Item15_chosen" onclick="price()"> 15. Popcorn ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item16" value="Item16_chosen" onclick="price()"> 16. Gamer ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item17" value="Item17_chosen" onclick="price()"> 17. Forest ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item18" value="Item18_chosen" onclick="price()"> 18. Pillar ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item19" value="Item19_chosen" onclick="price()"> 19. Snake ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item20" value="Item20_chosen" onclick="price()"> 20. Bumble ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item21" value="Item21_chosen" onclick="price()"> 21. Dungeon ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item22" value="Item22_chosen" onclick="price()"> 22. Mystical ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item23" value="Item23_chosen" onclick="price()"> 23. Grassy ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item24" value="Item24_chosen" onclick="price()"> 24. Warriors ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item25" value="Item25_chosen" onclick="price()"> 25. Fire ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item26" value="Item26_chosen" onclick="price()"> 26. Wood ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item27" value="Item27_chosen" onclick="price()"> 27. Sky ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item28" value="Item28_chosen" onclick="price()"> 28. Pure ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item29" value="Item29_chosen" onclick="price()"> 29. Crystal ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item30" value="Item30_chosen" onclick="price()"> 30. Pumpkin ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item31" value="Item31_chosen" onclick="price()"> 31. Mint ($5.00) <br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Your Total <input type="text" name="Total" value="$0" size="8" id="jom"></td>
<td> PST (7%) <input type="text" name="PST" value="$0"  size="6"></td>
<td colspan="2"> GST (7%) <input type="text" name="GST" value="$0" size="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Your Total Price Altogether: <input type="text" name="GrandTotal" value="$0" size="8"> </td>
</tr>
<td> Your Contact Name: </td>
<td> First <input type="text" name="firstname" size="15" maxlength="20"> Last <input type="text" name="LastName" size="15" maxlength="20"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Your Address: </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="city" size="20" maxlength="20"> </td>
<td> Province/State: </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="province" size="20" maxlength="30"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Phone number: </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="area" size="3" maxlength="5"> <input type="text" name="phone" size="8" maxlength="10"> </td>
</tr>
<td> Email Address: </td>
<td colspan="2"> <input type="text" name="email" size="30" maxlength="30"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" height="3"> <hr> </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Send Your Order"></td>
<td colspan="2" align="center"> <input type="reset" value="Reset Your Orders"> </td> 
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Check for the addition!

Comment: hello, you made it work, yes. but I am trying to make it so if ffor example, 3 are checked = $15 in "your total" box" and $15 in "your total price altogether" box. right now it's in the $0.00555 which doesnt

Comment: make sense at all

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Cost,Grand_Total,GST,PST;
function price() {
 Cost = 0;
// Cost = dollar(Cost);
 if (document.orderform.Item1.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item2.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item3.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item4.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item5.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item6.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item7.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item8.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item9.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item10.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item11.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item12.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item13.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item14.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item15.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item16.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item17.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item18.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item19.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item20.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item21.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item22.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item23.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item24.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item25.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item26.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item27.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item28.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item29.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}
 if (document.orderform.Item30.checked) {Cost = Cost + 5.00;}

 GST = (Cost*0.07);
 PST = (Cost*0.07);
 GST = dollar(GST);
 PST = dollar(PST);
 Grand_Total = parseFloat(Cost) + parseFloat(GST) + parseFloat(PST);
 Grand_Total = dollar(Grand_Total);
 document.orderform.Total.value = "$" + parseFloat(Cost).toFixed(2);
 document.orderform.GST.value = "$" + GST;
 document.orderform.PST.value = "$" + PST;
 document.orderform.GrandTotal.value = "$" + Grand_Total;
}

function dollar (amount) {
 amount = parseInt(amount*100);
 amount = parseFloat(amount/100);
 if (((amount) == Math.floor(amount))&&((amount - Math.floor(amount)) == 0))
 {
  amount = amount + ".00"
  return amount;
 }
 if (((amount*10) - Math.floor(amount*10)) == 0) {
  amount = amount + "0";
  return amount;
 }
 if (((amount*100 - Math.floor(amount*100))) == 0) {
  amount = amount;
  return amount;
 }
 return amount;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="orderform" action="mailto:xolilyle@gmail.com">
    <table style="margin-left: 22.5%; margin-top: 3%; position: absolute; font-size: 20px;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item1" value="Item1_chosen" onclick="price()"> 1. Dragon ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item2" value="Item2_chosen" onclick="price()"> 2. Galaxy ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item3" value="Item3_chosen" onclick="price()"> 3. Wolves ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item4" value="Item4_chosen" onclick="price()"> 4. Jaguar ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item5" value="Item5_chosen" onclick="price()"> 5. New Years ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item6" value="Item6_chosen" onclick="price()"> 6. Festive ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item7" value="Item7_chosen" onclick="price()"> 7. Fierce ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item8" value="Item8_chosen" onclick="price()"> 8. Support ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item9" value="Item9_chosen" onclick="price()"> 9. Luck ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item10" value="Item10_chosen" onclick="price()"> 10. Amor ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item11" value="Item11_chosen" onclick="price()"> 11. Halloween ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item12" value="Item12_chosen" onclick="price()"> 12. Domino ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item13" value="Item13_chosen" onclick="price()"> 13. Banana ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item14" value="Item14_chosen" onclick="price()"> 14. Sea ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item15" value="Item15_chosen" onclick="price()"> 15. Popcorn ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item16" value="Item16_chosen" onclick="price()"> 16. Gamer ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item17" value="Item17_chosen" onclick="price()"> 17. Forest ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item18" value="Item18_chosen" onclick="price()"> 18. Pillar ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item19" value="Item19_chosen" onclick="price()"> 19. Snake ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item20" value="Item20_chosen" onclick="price()"> 20. Bumble ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item21" value="Item21_chosen" onclick="price()"> 21. Dungeon ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item22" value="Item22_chosen" onclick="price()"> 22. Mystical ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item23" value="Item23_chosen" onclick="price()"> 23. Grassy ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item24" value="Item24_chosen" onclick="price()"> 24. Warriors ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item25" value="Item25_chosen" onclick="price()"> 25. Fire ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item26" value="Item26_chosen" onclick="price()"> 26. Wood ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item27" value="Item27_chosen" onclick="price()"> 27. Sky ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item28" value="Item28_chosen" onclick="price()"> 28. Pure ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item29" value="Item29_chosen" onclick="price()"> 29. Crystal ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item30" value="Item30_chosen" onclick="price()"> 30. Pumpkin ($5.00)
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Item31" value="Item31_chosen" onclick="price()"> 31. Mint ($5.00)
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Your Total
                <input type="text" name="Total" value="$0" size="8" id="jom">
            </td>
            <td> PST (7%)
                <input type="text" name="PST" value="$0" size="6">
            </td>
            <td colspan="2"> GST (7%)
                <input type="text" name="GST" value="$0" size="6"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Your Total Price Altogether:
                <input type="text" name="GrandTotal" value="$0" size="8"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Your Contact Name: </td>
            <td> First
                <input type="text" name="firstname" size="15" maxlength="20"> Last
                <input type="text" name="LastName" size="15" maxlength="20"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Your Address: </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="city" size="20" maxlength="20"> </td>
            <td> Province/State: </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="province" size="20" maxlength="30"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Phone number: </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="area" size="3" maxlength="5">
                <input type="text" name="phone" size="8" maxlength="10"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Email Address: </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" name="email" size="30" maxlength="30"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" height="3">
                <hr> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Send Your Order">
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="reset" value="Reset Your Orders"> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

`Cost = dollar(Cost);` What is the use of this line ? Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok , use  `parseFloat(Cost).toFixed(2)`  inorder to display decimal part.

Answer (score 0):

If the price is the same for all product then why do you writing that if condition for every checkbox?

I would suggest rewriting like this:

`price` function:

```
function price(cb) {
 if (cb.checked) { // if checked then add price
  Cost = Cost + 5.00;
 } 
 else // else substract price from the Cost
 {
  Cost = Cost - 5.00;
 }
  // your other code
}
```

In HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item1_chosen" onchange='price(this)'>
```

Working example with 3 product:

*Note: I have not checked dollar function, have a look at::), except that all working!*

```js
var Cost, Grand_Total, GST, PST;
Cost = 0.00;

function price(cb) {
 if (cb.checked) {
  Cost = Cost + 5.00;
 } else {
  Cost = Cost - 5.00;
 }

 GST = (Cost * 0.07);
 PST = (Cost * 0.07);
 GST = dollar(GST);
 PST = dollar(PST);
 Grand_Total = parseFloat(Cost) + parseFloat(GST) + parseFloat(PST);
 Grand_Total = dollar(Grand_Total);
 document.orderform.Total.value = "$" + Cost;
 document.orderform.GST.value = "$" + GST;
 document.orderform.PST.value = "$" + PST;
 document.orderform.GrandTotal.value = "$" + Grand_Total;
}

function dollar(amount) {
 amount = parseInt(amount * 100);
 amount = parseFloat(amount / 100);
 if (((amount) == Math.floor(amount)) && ((amount - Math.floor(amount)) == 0)) {
  amount = amount + ".00"
  return amount;
 }
 if (((amount * 10) - Math.floor(amount * 10)) == 0) {
  amount = amount + "0";
  return amount;
 }
 if (((amount * 100 - Math.floor(amount * 100)) == 0)) {
  amount = amount;
  return amount;
 }
 return amount;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="orderform" action="mailto:xolilyle@gmail.com">
<table style="margin-left: 22.5%; margin-top: 3%; position: absolute; font-size: 20px;">
<tr> <td colspan="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item1_chosen" onchange='price(this)'> 1. Dragon ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item2_chosen" onchange='price(this)'> 2. Galaxy ($5.00) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="Item3_chosen" onchange='price(this)'> 3. Wolves ($5.00) <br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Your Total <input type="text" name="Total" value="$0" size="8" id="jom"></td>
<td> PST (7%) <input type="text" name="PST" value="$0"  size="6"></td>
<td colspan="2"> GST (7%) <input type="text" name="GST" value="$0" size="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Your Total Price Altogether: <input type="text" name="GrandTotal" value="$0" size="8"> </td>
</tr>
<td> Your Contact Name: </td>
<td> First <input type="text" name="firstname" size="15" maxlength="20"> Last <input type="text" name="LastName" size="15" maxlength="20"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Your Address: </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="city" size="20" maxlength="20"> </td>
<td> Province/State: </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="province" size="20" maxlength="30"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Phone number: </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="area" size="3" maxlength="5"> <input type="text" name="phone" size="8" maxlength="10"> </td>
</tr>
<td> Email Address: </td>
<td colspan="2"> <input type="text" name="email" size="30" maxlength="30"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" height="3"> <hr> </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Send Your Order"></td>
<td colspan="2" align="center"> <input type="reset" value="Reset Your Orders"> </td> 
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

WHY HAVE **MUCH** WHEN YOU HAVE **SUCH** :-)

Tried to re-write your code with **Singleton Pattern(ES6)**. Hope you'll enjoy.

Moreover now the amount getting passed from item are decoupled from code, so that can vary as you'll define in checkbox values.

```js
class Cart {
    constructor(data) {
        if (Cart.exists) {
            return Cart.instance;
        }
        this._data = data;
        Cart.instance = this;
        Cart.exists = true;
        return this;
    }
    currencify(amount) {
        amount = parseInt(amount * 100);
        amount = parseFloat(amount / 100);
        if (((amount) == Math.floor(amount)) && ((amount - Math.floor(amount)) == 0)) {
            amount = amount + ".00"
            return amount;
        }
        if (((amount * 10) - Math.floor(amount * 10)) == 0) {
            amount = amount + "0";
            return amount;
        }
        if (((amount * 100 - Math.floor(amount * 100)) == 0)) {
            amount = amount;
            return amount;
        }
        return amount;
    }
    updateGrandTotal() {
        const price = this._data.length ? this._data.reduce((total = 0, num = 0) => total + num) : 0;
        const total = this.currencify(price);
        const GST = this.currencify(total * 0.07);
        const PST = this.currencify(total * 0.07);
        document.orderform.Total.value = `$ ${total}`;
        document.orderform.GST.value = `$ ${GST}`;
        document.orderform.PST.value = `$ ${PST}`;
        document.orderform.GrandTotal.value = `$ ${(parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(GST) + parseFloat(PST)).toFixed(2)}`;
        return total;
    }
    updateCart() {
        const checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="Item"]:checked');
        const values = [];
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(checkedBoxes, function (el) {
            values.push(parseFloat(el.value));
        });
        this._data = [...values];
        this.updateGrandTotal();
    }
}

const cart = new Cart;
const el = document.getElementById('container');
const updateCart = () => cart.updateCart()
const checkBoxes = el.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0, len = checkBoxes.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (checkBoxes[i].type === 'checkbox') {
        checkBoxes[i].onclick = updateCart;
    }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="orderform" action="mailto:xolilyle@gmail.com">
        <table style="margin-left: 22.5%; margin-top: 3%; position: absolute; font-size: 20px;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" id="container">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 1. Dragon ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 2. Galaxy ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 3. Wolves ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 4. Jaguar ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 5. New Years ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 6. Festive ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 7. Fierce ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 8. Support ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 9. Luck ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 10. Amor ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 11. Halloween ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 12. Domino ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 13. Banana ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 14. Sea ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 15. Popcorn ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 16. Gamer ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 17. Forest ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 18. Pillar ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 19. Snake ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 20. Bumble ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 21. Dungeon ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 22. Mystical ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 23. Grassy ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 24. Warriors ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 25. Fire ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 26. Wood ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 27. Sky ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 28. Pure ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 29. Crystal ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 30. Pumpkin ($5.00) <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Item" value="5"> 31. Mint ($5.00) <br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Your Total <input type="text" name="Total" value="$ 0" size="8" id="jom"></td>
                <td> PST (7%) <input type="text" name="PST" value="$ 0" size="6"></td>
                <td colspan="2"> GST (7%) <input type="text" name="GST" value="$ 0" size="6"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Your Total Price Altogether: <input type="text" name="GrandTotal" value="$ 0" size="8"> </td>
            </tr>
            <td> Your Contact Name: </td>
            <td> First <input type="text" name="firstname" size="15" maxlength="20"> Last <input type="text" name="LastName"
                    size="15" maxlength="20"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Your Address: </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="city" size="20" maxlength="20"> </td>
                <td> Province/State: </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="province" size="20" maxlength="30"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Phone number: </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="area" size="3" maxlength="5"> <input type="text" name="phone" size="8"
                        maxlength="10"> </td>
            </tr>
            <td> Email Address: </td>
            <td colspan="2"> <input type="text" name="email" size="30" maxlength="30"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" height="3">
                    <hr>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Send Your Order"></td>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"> <input type="reset" value="Reset Your Orders"> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```